# Why is the radius of convergence is $(-1/2, 1/2)$?

Tags: calculus, power-series

> What is the radius convergence of: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n}{n}x^{2n+3}$$

So we can take $x^3$ out of the sum: $$x^3 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n}{n}(x^2)^n$$

Now we substitute $y=x^2$: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n}{n}y^n$$.

Easy to see that the radius of convergence is $y=x^2\in [-\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4})$

Now, how do I get back to $x$ properly?

it should be $x\in(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ - Why is it open interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real $x$, the number  $x^2$ is in the interval $[-1/4,1/4)$ if and only if $|x|\lt\sqrt{1/4}=1/2$.

As to why open interval, note that at $x=\pm \frac{1}{2}$ we get the harmonic series, which diverges.

**Remark:** The substitution $y=x^2$ is a good idea if it makes things look more familiar, but one can also work directly with the series as given, using either the Ratio Test or the Root Test.

Comment: You want the left endpoint to be open, at least with the way you formulated the rest of your statement.

Comment: I think OP's statement with left endpoint closed is OK for $y$, it just so happens that $x^2$ cannot be negative.

Comment: I'm just nitpicking about "$x^2 \in [-1/4,1/4)$ iff $|x|<1/2$". This is actually true in this particular case (since $x^2$ is never negative anyway), but it would be clearer if you wrote "$x^2 \in (-1/4,1/4)$ iff $|x|<1/2$".